# For Abelian group $G$, show that $W_n = \{a \in G : \text{ord}(a) \mid n\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ for any positive integer $n$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

[image]

It seems to me that we are trying to show that $W_n$ is a subgroup of $(G,+)$
So I started with let $a1,a2$ be arbitrary elements in $W_n$.
And trying to show $a_1+a_2$ are still in $W_n$.
Then, I have $\text{ord}(a_1)= x$, where $n=xj_1$ for some integer $j_1$
And $\text{ord}(a_2)=y$, where $n=yj_2$ for some integer $j_2$.
Then I compute $a_1+a_2$ but I don't know how to make use of the previous information to finish the proof.

Comment: What happens if you raise this to the power $n$?

Comment: Hint: note that $a \in W_n$ if and only if $na = 0$ (where $0$ is the additive identity).

Comment: Then both a1^n and a2^n will be equal to e which is the identity element. But how about (a1+a2)^n?

Comment: Now use the fact that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Oh, so is it like since G is a abelian group, so a3=a1+a2 is also in G. But it does not imply a3^n =e right? Otherwise, how to make use of it's commutative property?

Comment: In an abelian group, $a_1^na_2^n = (a_1a_2)^n$

Answer (score 1):

Subgroup criterion.  $e\in W_n$.  Let $x,y\in W_n$.  Then $(xy^{-1})^n\stackrel{\text{G abelian}}=x^ny^{-n}=e\cdot e=e$.  Thus $xy^{-1}\in W_n$.

Here I have used repeatedly that $x^n=e\iff$ the order of $x$ divides $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assume that $a,b \in W_n$. We want to show that $a+b \in W_n$ as well, but you know that $$\underbrace{a+\cdots+a}_{\mbox{$n$ times}} = 0 \quad \mbox{and}\quad \underbrace{b+\cdots+b}_{\mbox{$n$ times}} = 0.$$So $$\underbrace{(a+b)+\cdots+(a+b)}_{\mbox{$n$ times}} = \underbrace{a+\cdots+a}_{\mbox{$n$ times}} + \underbrace{b+\cdots+b}_{\mbox{$n$ times}} = 0+0 = 0,$$by associativity and commutativity of $+$. Thus ${\rm ord}(a+b) \mid n$, showing that $a+b \in W_n$. Also, note that $$\underbrace{0+\cdots + 0}_{\mbox{$n$ times}} = 0,$$so ${\rm ord}(0) \mid n$ and $0 \in W_n$. Lastly, if $a \in W_n$, we have $$\underbrace{(-a)+\cdots+(-a)}_{\mbox{$n$ times}} = -\underbrace{\big(a+\cdots+a\big)}_{\mbox{$n$ times}} = -0 = 0,$$so ${\rm ord}(-a) \mid n$ and $-a \in W_n$.